# Property 'type' does not exist on type 'object', even after `"type" in` check

Tags: typescript, typeguards

[This code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIBMCmBJCBVCSA2SIRgF4YAKeZALhgFcwBreAdzAEoiA+AKBjkSRgCEhYmGrZsMAGSTuMKAE8ADkhAAzXsiLCYAIhAAjAFZJgUHVJk8dC5eYCWYDf2mybK9eSQA6N1uI7oACcHAHNzFx5PHyV+YX8AKQBlAA0AFSQADzMAbiA) fails to compile:

```
const nodeIsUseless = (node: unknown) =>
  node !== null &&
  typeof node === "object" &&
  "type" in node &&
  typeof node.type === "string" &&
  node.type === "JSXText";
```

because on the last 2 lines:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'object'.(2339)

...which I can understand by itself, but I do not understand why after `"type" in node` check, TS infers `node` to still be of type `object` instead of type `{ type: unknown; [key: string]: unknown }`, which [would not trigger error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIBMCmBJCBVCSA2SIRgF4YAKeZALhgG8YoBPABySoFcwBreAdzAG4YAbQ5J6VaACcAlmADmAXTaceYGAF8AlEQB8AKBh0mSEADM4iJADoGzIoWIAiSTNkOYAMnf7zya0buOAFIAygAaACpIAB5QDnxAA).

Comment: I can't think of any way to satisfy the compiler here without a [cast and a runtime check inside a user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAciAJgUxgXhgCgB4BcMArmANZggDuYAlEXvBDAN4xQCeADmkdAE5wwAcxgBfLAD5WAKBgxQkWBywxGAQ2ZtOPPlEEjxAbjkx+aKMX5gYKgGR323NCABmarJmwByEACMAKzRgKG8YByceN1wNLUjeGAEhUTFaADodDC8fJJFvEzEZGUVoGEp0AEkIAFUINAAbNAhmbBxyhNIKajopUwRkdDbUNFpwu1N2jOdPbAAiACkAZQANABU0PChZkxkgA), hopefully someone cleverer than I sees this. I also realize that isn't really the crux of the question which is about inference.

Comment: Uh oh, looks like even [Matt Pocock](https://twitter.com/mattpocockuk/status/1563103687849181186) is struggling with this :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the code is correct, TypeScript doesn't have the capability to infer `{ type: unknown }` from `"type" in node` but this feature [is currently in development](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50666)

---

2022-09-21 update: with the merge of the aforementionned PR, this can now be done in typescript@next and should be available in typescript@latest soon.

See also the [discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420457/8186898) about this answer.

Comment: this feature has been implemented. With the merge of "[Improve checking of in operator #50666](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50666)", TypeScript does have that capability.

Comment: Had to switch my typescript config from `4.8.3` to `4.9.5`.

Answer (score 4):

You should do this:

```
const nodeIsUseless = (node: unknown) =>
  node !== null &&
  node !== undefined &&
  node instanceof Object &&
  !Array.isArray(node) &&
  "type" in node &&
  typeof node["type"] === "string" &&
  node["type"] === "JSXText";
```

Just need to check `insonceof` instead of `typeof` and use `object["key"]`  method to access values instead of `.key`.
Also, it's good practice to ensure that the item isn't an Array since `instonceof [] === 'object'` too

Comment: What version of typescript did you do this with?  Doesn't seem to be working for me

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the TypeScript built-in [`in` operator type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) is not as powerful as you expect it to be.

From a bare `object`, it will *not* infer that the tested property is available. It can infer that it is indeed there, *only* if it is *already potentially available*, e.g. in one of a union-ed types. I.e. the control flow will not make the tested property "appear", but only try to differentiate between union-ed types.

```
declare const o: object;
if ("type" in o) {
  o.type // Error: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'object'.
//^? object
}

declare const u: Number | String; // Note: using class only for the sake of the demo
if ("toFixed" in u) {
  u.toFixed(); // Okay
//^? Number
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3kgXNgRgFbgYDcAUAJYBm8AFAEQYCeADiA-JStgJTwBvcvGwA6Fu3gB6KfACiMGEhh4ACkvYwW8AOQSQO+MCQg08FEiwgAHpUzYe+3UiIkdo8jIB6AfnIBfcnJQSFgEZHQsAFc8ADkogFt8EBh4AB94AGUMGG4AcwoaeiYkADFKaxBgTm54KP4hESjxMoqqul5SaVkAeQBrKGZPKV8A8iA)

---

In your case, you could therefore specify a union for the `node` argument, with a possible type of e.g. `{ type: unknown }`.

However, the `unknown` top type [*absorbs*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) all other types in a union, so it would have to be replaced by everything else, e.g. using the special type `{}` to represent common types:

```
const nodeIsUseless = (node: undefined | null | {} | { type: unknown }) =>
  node !== null &&
  typeof node === "object" &&
  //     ^? {} | { type: unknown } | undefined
  "type" in node &&
  //        ^? {} | { type: unknown }
  typeof node.type === "string" && // Okay
  //     ^? { type: unknown }
  node.type === "JSXText"; // Okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIBMCmBJCBVCSA2SIRgF4YAKeZALhgFcxkAzASzCQRgB85rtsOYBvAL59+MKAE8ADkiq0A1vADuYGIICURAHwAoGHERIYAQkLEw3XgDJLusVKQh6+5EVMwARCABGAKyTAodxhrWwB6UL1IgD0Aflt3CWkg5mdDEL1wyKyYWNtEhydyJAA6fNdid2gAJ2YAcyD0mEys3L0i0vtyjwApAGUADQAVJAAPQIBubSA)